# Glassfish JNDI InitialContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jndi

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to connect to Glassfish EJB but I have a problem.

When doing the following:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    this.url = "10.128.128.135";
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", this.url);
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
    final Context context = new InitialContext(props);
    this.userEJB = (UserEJB) context.lookup("ejb/User#com.xxxx.xxxxx.ejb.UserEJB");
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("EJB client initialized with url: " + url);
```

i get this exception:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:350)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at com.xxxxx.xxxx.gwt.server.delegate.UserDelegate.<init>(UserDelegate.java:47)
at com.xxxxx.xxxx.gwt.server.rpc.LoginServiceImpl.<clinit>(LoginServiceImpl.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1097)
at com.xxxxx.xxxx.gwt.MyHeadersFilter.doFilter(MyHeadersFilter.java:28)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

After that i tried adding the following props as well:

```
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
```

and then i get another exception instead:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:347)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:384)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:329)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:477)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at com.xxxxx.xxxx.gwt.server.delegate.UserDelegate.<init>(UserDelegate.java:46)
at com.xxxxx.xxxx.gwt.server.rpc.LoginServiceImpl.<clinit>(LoginServiceImpl.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1097)
at com.xxxxx.xxxx.gwt.MyHeadersFilter.doFilter(MyHeadersFilter.java:28)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

So how do I lookup my EJB?

Comment: hello are you using netbeans?

Comment: Looks like a classpath problem. Please edit the question with the complete error stacktrace and the libs which you are packaging with the client.

Comment: Will do that first thing on monday morning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with GWT classpath. Deploying the application works fine, and now i have fixed the GWT project by removing the jars from the GWT classpath and letting the application find them on its own. Eg:

```
[WARN] Server class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/Users/linde/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-servlet/2.5.1/gwt-servlet-2.5.1.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
```

Now both dev mode and deploy works. Although remote debug(eg set up GWT dev mode running and connect from a remote computer) doesn't work and gives me a weird  error. Maybe this is a bug in GWT 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you have registered the ejb resource in the glassfish administration console
localhost\4848

You can access the admin console on netbeans by selecting the services tab -- servers-- right click glassfish--choose start admin console.

Check that the EJB is registered in the server.

Also look up resource injection for further information on how to access resources from java applications.

I hope this is helpful.

Please post your code next time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look up what you said and verify that everything is as it should be. Unfortunately I can't post too big chunks of the code since it's not open source, but I will make it more clear in further posts. Thanks again, i'll be back and accept the answer if it helped!

Comment: Are you using netbeans?

Comment: No, I'm using eclipse for this project.

Comment: I have now looked things up within glassfish and i have a IIOP Listener under the ORB section and well there is a EJB Container which seems to be as it should. Most of the stuff is default except the database connectors